# How can i implement a open graph (http://ogp.me/) to use my custom tags in another website?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, namespaces, facebook-opengraph, xml-namespaces, custom-tag

I've reviewed http://ogp.me/ but couldn't find a solution. What I want to do is:

defining a `xmlns` like:

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

set up an `id` for that website like:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="1234" />
```

and use that tags as a component in html like:

```
<myTag:video src="somurl">/</myTag>
```

Could you give me any idea how can I implement such an methodology for my system?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Create own `namespace` and use tags from that `namespace`? Or instruct Facebook to fetch data from your own tags (this isn't possible)?

Comment: okey, more clearly i will build plugins for other websites, think about comment plugin of facebook. i will serve all html, from my services, all i want to do is generate custom tags and use them just like i've explained above.

Comment: So in short you're trying to implement and use `namespaces` in a way similar to how Facebook implemented this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found another solution to make a dynamic components that serves from my application to external websites like a comment plugin. Just use js to get informaition and push your html inside that website. xmlns definition is not a good idea, also facebook cancel its fbml structure to pure javascript & css via api communication. Thats the valid way.